# Rules Engine on Azure

Tags: json, azure, avro, azure-eventhub, streaming-analytics

I'm new to Azure and i'm trying to understand rules engine on streaming analytics.
Could you please help me understand the following.

1)  Implementation of a JSON format for complex rule definition
2)  Implementation of a JSON format for time-series processes / rules
3)  Implementation of complex rules in ASA
4)  Implementation of time-series rules in ASA

Regards